# Present continuous to express future arangements conditionally

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous

I was taught that we can use present continous to express future that has been arranged. For example, "I am staying home today".

Today, I stumbled upon on the following example: "I am staying in today unless my friends call me". Can we use it for conditionals like this?

Comment: What do you think? Why do you doubt it?

Comment: That sounds ok to me but I am a bit confused that is not something that happens for sure

Comment: It's a colloquial way of putting things, an alternative to **I will be staying in unless....** In some instances it might be an after-thought. **I am going swimming today....unless it rains.**